# descompress bundle.js to reactjs

Tags: reactjs, gulp, bundle

it turns out that I had a problem with the editable files of a project in react js, now I only have the bundle
http://entre-lineas.co/public/assets/app.vendor.bundle.js

it is possible to decompress these bundles, and pass them to react editable

thanks for any help

Comment: sort of, but it's not going to be what you want. http://unminify.com/

Comment: i thanks, but no is the solucion, becase the uniminfy is javascript, and i find a reactjs

Comment: right, that's because webpack changes your code. I told you it wasn't gonna be what you want but it's pretty much your only option aside from maybe recovering the file